# Symbolic links to external HDD not always working after boot-up

Tags: symbolic-link

I created some symbolic links to certain parts of my HDD (Ubuntu's on SSD). Sometimes, right after boot-up, they don't work and appear as corrupted files. I have to open my HDD through devices list and only then do they start working.

What is the problem here? I've never had problems with shortcuts in Windows :/

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but do you have the devices set to automount in fstab? I've had some issues like this and it usually was a problem with my fstab. Reference on fstab here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab, or if you post your fstab file (`cat /etc/fstab`) I can try to give some more specific help.

Comment: As far as I can see, the HDD does not have a -noauto option on fstab. Could the default auto option not work?